# Left-pad hours and minutes with a leading zero to two places (each) in a loop

Tags: php, text-formatting, time-format

so i got this script for the moment :

```
<select class="n-select" name="heure-event" id="heure-event">
    <option selected="selected"></option>
    <?php
        for ( $heures = 0 ; $heures <= 23 ; $heures++ ){
            for ( $minutes = 0 ; $minutes <= 45 ; $minutes += 15 ){ 
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $heures.':'.$minutes;?>:00">
        <?php
            echo $heures.':'.$minutes;
        ?>
    </option>   
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>                    
</select>
```

It works very well, but the little problem : `1:15`, `1:0`, etc.

I want: `01:15` and `1:00`.

Can somebody help me? I need probably to check if `$i` is `< 10` then add `'0.$i'` or something like this?

Comment: Take a look to http://php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php it returns a formatted string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

```
<?php

$hour = 1;
$minute = 9;

echo strftime('%H:%M', mktime($hour, $minute)); // 01:09
```

Answer (score 3):

That's just a display problem. Don't store 'formatted' data, especially when it's numeric.

So... for the value, store 1:15, but display 01:15, via

```
value="<?php echo "$heure:$minutes" ?>"><?php echo sprintf('%02d:%02d', $heures, $minutes) ?></option>
```

[sprintf()](http://php.net/sprintf)

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.   Specifically: `printf('<option value="%1$d:%2$d">%1$02d:%2$02d</option>', $heures, $minutes);`

Answer (score 0):

```
                                <option value="<?php echo sprintf('%02d:%02d', $heures, $minutes) ?>:00"><?php echo sprintf('%02d:%02d', $heures, $minutes) ?></option>
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.  Specifically: `printf('<option value="%1$02d:%2$02d:00">%1$02d:%2$02d</option>', $heures, $minutes);`

Answer (score -3):

```
$days = array('' => '');
for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++)
{
    $days[$i] = $i;
}

$months = array('' => '');
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
    $months[$i] = $i;
}

$hours = array('' => '');
for ($i = 9; $i <= 18; $i++)
{
    $hours[$i] = sprintf('%02d', $i);
}

$mins = array('' => '');
for ($i = 0; $i <= 45; $i += 15)
{
    $mins[$i] = sprintf('%02d', $i);
}

$years = array(2012 => 2012, 2013 => 2013);
```

Edit: Woops, completely misread the question, apologies. Simply use `sprintf` to format the numbers correctly:

```
$heures = sprintf('%02d', $heures);
$minutes= sprintf('%02d', $minutes);
<option value="<?php echo $heures.':'.$minutes;?>:00"><?php echo $heures.':'.$minutes;?></option>
```